# Create and fill non-constant Eigen matrix in one line?

Tags: c++, eigen

How can I create and initialize a non-constant eigen matrix in one line? Here is an example of what I'm trying to do with 2 lines,

```
auto a = Eigen::Matrix<int, 4, 4>{};
a.fill(0);
```

or

```
a.fill(1);
a.fill(2);
// etc.
```

Comment: http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/group__TutorialAdvancedInitialization.html

Comment: @sneftel, I updated my question.  I should have specified that I have different values I want to initialize with.  The **advanced init** link has initialization for `0` but I'm looking for a way to initialize with a specific value of my choosing.

Comment: You can remove the line break between both lines.

Comment: @J'e Read the entire page. It also says "Similarly, the static method `Constant(value)` sets all coefficients to `value`."

Comment: Also, avoid `auto` with Eigen-expressions, unless you know what you are doing.

Comment: @chtz, put this in an answer and I'll accept it.  I was avoiding the use of `::Constant` because it returns a constant.  Defining a non-constant matrix (not auto)  and assigning it the `::Constant(value)` works.

Answer (score 0):

In C++ most whitespaces are not necessary. You could remove most whitespaces and write all your code in one line. This

```
auto a = Eigen::Matrix<int, 4, 4>{}; a.fill(0); a.fill(1); a.fill(2);
```

is a valid one-liner in C++.

Comment: If you removed *all* the whitespaces, your lines would start with `autoa=Eigen::Matrix...` which would not be valid (unless, e.g., `autoa` was a previously declared identifier)

Comment: @chtz Thank you. I fixed it.